# ayuda con Pivot con consultas y fechas sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problemita con esta consulta  en sql server que mostrare   abajo  y es que quiero que me salga la fecha completa , pero solo logro sacar el mes o el año solamente, aca dejo las tablas , La fecha la tengo como DATETIME

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select * from(
SELECT        dbo.Productos.NombreProducto as producto,
year(dbo.Pedidos.FechaPedido) as f,count(dbo.[Detalles de 
 pedidos].Cantidad) as cantidad
 FROM            dbo.[Detalles de pedidos] INNER JOIN
                     dbo.Pedidos ON dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].IdPedido = 
  dbo.Pedidos.IdPedido INNER JOIN
                     dbo.Productos ON dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].IdProducto = 
   dbo.Productos.IdProducto
                     group by NombreProducto,Cantidad,FechaPedido) as tabla
                      pivot(sum(cantidad ) for f in ([1996],[1997],[1998])) 
  as pvt
```

como ven solo puedo  sacar el año pero no me sale con el dia y el mes, ovbiamente usando el pivot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería-...

Lo que quiero es que salga como esta en esta imagen , pero en el pivot
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál fecha completa quieres? Estás agrupando por año ¿Quieres que salga 1996-01-01 como título de la columna para representar el año?

Comment: Aunque técnicamente no estás agrupando nada.

Comment: Bueno, sale el año, porque utilizas la función `year()`. Sospecho que lo que ocurre es que no entiendes el código que pides que se modifique. Si quieres utilizar otras columnas, considero que el cambio es _simple_ si entiendes el código. Por otro lado, las implicaciones de sacar una columna por fecha, para 3 años, son que vas a tener una consulta con 1095 columnas (si ninguno es bisiesto, si no serían 1096) ¿Estás seguro que eso es lo que quieres hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la fecha completa para hacer el pivote.

Te dejo un ejemplo con 3 fechas:

```
select * 
  from (select   dbo.Productos.NombreProducto as producto
               , dbo.Pedidos.FechaPedido as f
               , count(dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].Cantidad) as cantidad
          from dbo.[Detalles de pedidos] 
               inner join dbo.Pedidos on dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].IdPedido = dbo.Pedidos.IdPedido 
               inner join dbo.Productos on dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].IdProducto = dbo.Productos.IdProducto
          group by NombreProducto, Cantidad, FechaPedido
       ) as tabla
       pivot(sum(cantidad ) for f in ([19960704],[19960705],[19960708])
            )  as pvt
```

Que te arrojaría un resultado como este:

```
producto   19960704    19960705    19960708
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Producto 1 3           7           5
Producto 2 7           2           4
Producto 3 2           5           8

(3 rows affected)
```

Si quieres ver la fecha *con formato* en los encabezados de las columnas, entonces, utiliza la función `convert` para darle el formato que deseas a la fecha, por ejemplo:

```
select * 
  from (select   dbo.Productos.NombreProducto as producto
               , convert(varchar, dbo.Pedidos.FechaPedido, 106) as f
               , count(dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].Cantidad) as cantidad
          from dbo.[Detalles de pedidos] 
               inner join dbo.Pedidos on dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].IdPedido = dbo.Pedidos.IdPedido 
               inner join dbo.Productos on dbo.[Detalles de pedidos].IdProducto = dbo.Productos.IdProducto
          group by NombreProducto, Cantidad, FechaPedido
       ) as tabla
       pivot(sum(cantidad ) for f in ([04 Jul 1996],[05 Jul 1996],[08 Jul 1996])
            )  as pvt
```

Que te dará un resultado como este:

```
producto   04 Jul 1996 05 Jul 1996 06 Jul 1996
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Producto 1 3           7           5
Producto 2 7           2           4
Producto 3 2           5           8

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @jachguate